# card reader module throwing errors while installing rts_bpp

Tags: drivers

I am trying to install rts_bpp driver for my card reader in 13.04 from the following site. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876

While executing `sudo dpkg -i rts-bpp-dkms_1.1_all.deb`, I am getting the following errors: Please help.
(I am not an advanced user in linux and pretty new. )

```
#######################################
Setting up rts-bpp-dkms (1.1) ...

Loading tarball for rts_bpp-1.1
Loading /var/lib/dkms/rts_bpp/1.1/3.0.0-17-generic/x86_64...

DKMS: ldtarball completed.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rts_bpp/1.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/rts_bpp-1.1

DKMS: add completed.
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-19-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.8.0-19-generic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 22, in <module>
    import apport
ImportError: No module named apport
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-19-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rts_bpp/1.1/build/make.log for more information.
####################################################
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to use your card reader even without this package working? There is a new driver in the Linux 3.8, rtsx, that is supposed to replace the rts. It works for me, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The kernel is 3.8.0-25-generic but still the card reader won't work. I am still searching for a ubuntu solution. There must be a tweak or something for this in ubuntu to work. Hope google shoots up something.